# How to insert CouchDB documents in bulk?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, couchdb, bulkinsert

I'm tasked with modifying a legacy app so that users can upload payroll adjustments in bulk. Currently they have to fill out a form and input the data item by item, hitting submit after each one. I'm giving them the ability to upload a CSV file containing tons of adjustments at once.

On the server they are inserting items into Couch one by one, like this:

```
function wsapiPOST(req, res, next) {
  var path = req.path.substr(6)
    , url = couchPath + path + requestUtil.buildQueryString(req);

  request.post({
    url: url,
    headers: { 'content-type': 'application/json' },
    body: JSON.stringify(req.body)
  },function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err) {
      if (resp) {
        res.writeHead(resp.statusCode);
        res.end(body);
      } else { // This would happen if the request timed out
        res.writeHead(408);
        res.end('timeout');
      }
    }
  }).pipe(res);
}
```

The Couch URL is built dynamically.

`req.body` contains the properties for a single item.

[image]

I'm new to Couch but I'm not sure how to send multiple documents for insertion in a single operation. I could throw the `request.post` call into a loop as is, but I imagine that's not going to be very performant.

I just need pointed in the right direction for bulk insertion into Couch via its REST API.

Comment: Can you just send an array to the rest api?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [bulk document API](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/1.6.1/api/database/bulk-api.html#db-bulk-docs) to insert (and even update) multiple documents.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [nano](https://github.com/dscape/nano) - there is a bulk insert option.

Comment: This is actually what I ended up using in case anyone else is wondering. Nano provides an intuitive node API for the bulk document couch API . I'll leave the other one as the answer since that is actually the direct answer to my question, but nano really is great and lightweight. I recommend it.